# Hi, I made a Rebirth System, But, how do i double the price each time

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value < 300 then
        script.Parent.Text = "Not Enough!"
        wait(2)
        script.Parent.Text = "1 REBIRTH          │       500  CLICKS"
    end
    if  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value >= 300 then       
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value =  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value +1
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value = 0
        game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Gems.Value =  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Gems.Value + 10
    end 
end)
```

Comment: In the future, you should post more than just the title and your code. Please take a moment and read the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is multiply by two, not add by one. Try this:

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value < 300 then

    script.Parent.Text = "Not Enough!"
    wait(2)
    script.Parent.Text = "1 REBIRTH          │       500  CLICKS"
    end
if  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value >= 300 then       
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value =  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Rebirths.Value *2
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Clicks.Value = 0
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Gems.Value =  game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Gems.Value + 10
    end 
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the cost of the next rebirth using the values available to you. Then you need to update the text and the cost based on those values.

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats
    local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
    local rebirths = leaderstats.Rebirths
    local gems = leaderstats.Gems

    local baseRebirthCost = 300
    local currentRebirthCost = baseRebirthCost * (2 ^ rebirths.Value)

    if clicks.Value < currentRebirthCost then
        script.Parent.Text = "Not Enough!"
        wait(2)
        script.Parent.Text = string.format("1 REBIRTH          │       %d  CLICKS", currentRebirthCost)
    else      
        rebirths.Value += 1
        clicks.Value = 0
        gems.Value += 10
    end 
end)
```

This will make the rebirth cost increase relative to the number of rebirths :

| Rebirths | Calculation | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 300 * 2^0 | 300 |
| 1 | 300 * 2^1 | 600 |
| 2 | 300 * 2^2 | 1,200 |
| 3 | 300 * 2^3 | 2,400 |
| 4 | 300 * 2^4 | 4,800 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 20 | 300 * 2^20 | 314,572,800 |

Comment: I should note that this code will only update the values on the client-side. If you want everyone to see the changes to these leaderstats, you should use a RemoteEvent and have the changes calculated in a server Script.